# Run the callback function of hcaptcha in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, puppeteer, captcha, hcaptcha

Is there any way to run this function in puppeteer to submit the hcaptcha?
I already loaded the h-captcha-response of the captcha into the textfield I just need to run the callback in puppeteer to submit the captcha-response...

**Callback Function**

[image: Callback Function]

Comment: Is `hcaptcha` available directly in the console, on this page ?

Comment: @Jaspal yes i can run window.hcaptcha

Comment: you can use `hcaptcha.execute()` to trigger it programatically. Checkout the docs here https://docs.hcaptcha.com/configuration#hcaptchaexecutewidgetid

Comment: @Jaspal `hcaptcha.execute()` just open the captcha to solve again. But i want to call the callback function for handleSubmit because i already have the h-captcha-response i just want to know how to submit it.....

Comment: hcaptcha.getResponseGet the captcha's id somehow and then poll it's response using `hcaptcha.getResponse` as mentioned in the docs right about `execute`. Other way around, you can pass `async: true` to `hcaptcha.execute()` for receiving a `Promise` back which triggers when it's resolved. So try to use `execute` for opening it up the first time ..

Answer (score -1):

I’ve had the same problem. This is a pain since most hcaptcha’s have two pages, thus, the “verify answers” button, which SHOULD trigger the callback function, is unavailable. I have found an imperfect way to trigger the callback function authenticates the response. The AnyCaptchaCallbackHooker is a chrome extension that creates its own html button that you can then click to trigger the callback function. I have no idea how it works in the backend but this definitely has worked for me. Here are the docs:

https://docs.anycaptcha.com/extensions/bypass-hcaptcha-funcaptcha-callback-with-extension

Hope this helps. I will be following this thread because I am very interested in figuring out a better solution too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).